# How to disable Komodo Edit's update suggestion?

Tags: editor, text-editor, komodoedit

The update screen that comes everytime is really annoying. How should I stop further suggesting?

I'm running `Komodo Edit, version 7.1.2, build 10678, platform linux-x86_64.
Built on Fri Aug 17 19:51:14 2012`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at - http://community.activestate.com/faq/disable-or-modify-komodo-auto-update-feature

Gotta ask though - why don't you want to update to 7.1.3? Or 8.0 for that matter, which was released a while ago.

Comment: I found this answer more than 2 years later looking for the way to turn this off. The answer is - it's not always a good idea to update versions. Sometimes stability of keeping the same version on a machine is more practical. When I go to a new machine I may try the new version and see if anything's actually better.

Answer (score 0):

Exact labels may be different (as I'm using 8.0 on OS X at the moment), but the general location of these settings should be similar across versions and platforms:

If you're referring to the "Start Page," try going to "Preferences>Appearance" and uncheck the  "Show Komodo Komodo Start Page on startup" option.

If you're referring to notifications directly from ActiveState, make sure the setting under "Preferences>Projects and Workspace>ActiveState Notification Message" labeled "Enable notification messages from ActiveState" is unselected.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but problem is with the window that I put it's picture.